# CodeBlocks on Mac are not reading file

Tags: c++, macos, codeblocks, fstream, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A;
    ifstream file("file.txt"); // there is a single "8" in the file
    file >> A;
    cout << A; // I get 0 always


    return 0;
}
```

While I'm not new to CodeBlocks, I'm new to CodeBlocks on Mac. I have changed the "Execution working directory" and it still does not work, please help.

Comment: i have read before that we should set execution directory in build target properties have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the execution working directory.. When you're reading from file, try writing the full directory where is that file, for example:

```
// this is your file.txt location
ifstream file("C:\\Desktop\\file.txt"); // this is for Windows
```

and then run a program.
If it still doesn't work, try watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De6trY8FRYY